# An alternating series that converges to zero

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find an example for an alternating series that converges to zero.

The form of the series I'm looking for is something like that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n}}{a_n} \quad s.t \quad a_n > 0\; \; \; \forall n\in\mathbb N$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using sin\cos but it didn't really worked out... @Integrand

Comment: Do you mean the series for sine and cosine?

Comment: Do you know any series $\sum a_n$ with $a_n > 0$ that converges to $0$?(try any $p$-series you're familiar with). For any such sequence $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ will converge too (see if you can figure out why). This essentially shows that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: Thank you both, I  think I've got something:
$(a_n) = (1, 1, \frac12, \frac12,...,\frac 1n, \frac 1n,...)$ 
Does it work? @OsamaGhani

Comment: @Integrand Yes, but maybe it's much easier than I thought.

Comment: Not the best p-series to use. Recall that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ doesn’t even converge. Why not consider $\sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{n^2}$? To show it converges notice that $\sum -\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \sum (-1)^n \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ with the inequality being true term wise. Do you see why this converges now?